# What url to put in jQuery AJAX load() method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, methods, load

I am testing this load() method of jQuery AJAX, and I have my test web site in my computer, so when I open index.html url is something like this: file:///C:/Users/.../App/index.html

But if I put this url to load() method it returns nothing - error.

I am trying with this code:

```
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load('file:///C:/Users/.../App/index.html #test', function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
});
```

Where in my index.html id="test" is this:

```
<div id="test">Test string</div>
```

I have also included this script to my app:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But result is always 0, any idea why?

Realy thanks for any advice and help.

Comment: For security reason, javascript cannot access to local filesystem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX calls to local filesystem won't work. You need to install locally a web server and use a url in a form of `http://localhost/index.html`

Comment: so if I put my app to server, than I just use url of what page I whant to load data, e.g. in my scenario 'http://mydomain/index.html Thanks for answer

Comment: Yes, but still you can test your application locally, before putting to a remote server (mydomain). Just install a web server like Apache HTTP Server (but any would do) on your computer and open your application in a browser (like http://localhost/somepage.html ). You don't need to specify the domain name in URL. '/index.html' should be enough. That way you can easily move the application afterwards, and it works regardless of server on which it is deployed. It will allow you to develop and test your application locally and then without a need for any further modification copy to real server